# Drupal has any asynchronous function to use on server side?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Not queuing a job, not a ajax call from client, just initiate another job purely on the server side asynchronously, is there a way Drupal(7.x) can do something like this?

Comment: That's what queuing a job is...

Comment: What kind of event would start that job? Does it start itself on a server cron or does a user action triggers it?

Comment: In one specific case,  after a node is successfully saved. Server can do more stuff without interfering with normal Drupal behavior user sees..

Answer (score 1):

The achieve this, you would need a process, or several processes, to run in the background and execute your asynchronous task. Being a (traditional) PHP application, Drupal does not provide such process. Depending on your server configuration, the PHP processes that run Drupal to handle HTTP requests are stopped or sit idle between these requests. And when they start, they use a clean state. They are also required to die at the end of processing an HTTP request and, AFAIK, there is no option for them to linger a little bit to finish things. So there is no process available to execute your asynchronous tasks.

Using Drupal Queue API, you can easily enqueue your task and have a external process pick and process them asynchronously. You likely don't want them to be processed only during Drupal cron run, which would be the default behavior of a queue in Drupal. Instead, you can use a queue manger like Gearman, Beanstalkd or even Redis and have a separated process listen to it, collect enqueued items and process them as soon as possible.

The [Beanstalkd integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/beanstalkd) provides a daemon script to process enqueued items in the background, effectively offering a ready to use solution.